# How to use XSLT2.0 in BizTalk?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2020

I'm trying to using XSLT 2.0 in BizTalk 2020. But I'm getting this below error.

'current-dateTime()' is an unknown XSLT function.

How to get rid of this? Do I need Saxon Engine to use 2.0?

[image]

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Comment: Yes @Dijkgraaf.

Comment: Currently I've used embedded C# script inside the XSL file to get the current date time in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Yes, C# inside the XSL file is how the BizTalk mapper does it when you use the Date and Time functoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the Saxon Engine if you want to use a later version of XSLT.

See [What’s new in BizTalk Server 2020: XSLT 3.0 Support](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2020/12/02/whats-new-in-biztalk-server-2020-xslt-3-0-support/) (Sandro Periara's blog)

> BizTalk’s default XSL transform engine implementation is based on .Net Framework XSLT Transformations. This support is limited to XSLT 1.0.

> Starting with BizTalk Server 2020, users can choose Saxon:registered: 9 (Saxon 9 HE) as the XSLT transform engine. But most importantly, it will be possible to plug-in your own custom XSLT transform engine.

If you want to use XLST 1.0 to get the date, then just use the same method that is created when you use the out of the box Date and Time functoid in the BizTalk mapper.

```
<xsl:variable name="var:v2" select="userCSharp:DateCurrentDateTime()" /> 

<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp">
<![CDATA[ public string RemoveSpaces(string stringWithSpaces)
public string DateCurrentDateTime()
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    string curdate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string curtime = dt.ToString("T", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    string retval = curdate + "T" + curtime;
    return retval;
}
]]> 
</msxsl:script>
```